# Problema ao criar uma foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Criei uma tabela `tbl_cond` com uma `PRIMARY KEY` chamada `ID_cond`

Ao criar uma segunda tabela com uma `FOREIGN KEY`, sendo ela a `ID_cond` da `tbl_cond`, coloquei o seguinte código.

```
use db_clientes
create table tbl_proprietarios
(ID_proprietario SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
name varchar(50) not null,
email varchar(50) not null,
constraint ID_cond foreign key (ID_cond) 
references tbl_cond(ID_cond)
)
```

Quando dou <kbd>F5</kbd> para criar a tabela, aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> "Mensagem 1769, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 2 A chave estrangeira
>   'ID_cond' faz referência à coluna inválida 'ID_cond' na tabela de
>   referência 'tbl_proprietarios'. Mensagem 1750, Nível 16, Estado 0,
>   Linha 2 Não foi possível criar a restrição ou o índice. Consulte os
>   erros anteriores."

Já tentei algumas opções, mas não consegui visualizar uma saída para este problema.

Comment: Crie um campo ID_cond em sua tabela tbl_proprietarios. Ao criar a constraint você está dizendo que este campo, que deveria existir, referencia uma linha da tabela tbl_cond com mesmo conteúdo.

Answer (score 2):

Você está criando uma constraint com uma coluna que não existe, precisa criar o campo na tabela `tbl_proprietarios` para referenciar a `Foreign Key`.

```
create table tbl_proprietarios
(
    ID_proprietario SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    name varchar(50) not null,
    email varchar(50) not null,
    id_condicao int,
    CONSTRAINT FK_id_condicao FOREIGN KEY (id_condicao)
    REFERENCES tbl_cond(ID_cond)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ao que parece, o problema diz que a coluna da sua tabela `tbl_proprietarios` está inválida. Creio que você não criou o atributo no momento da criação da tabela:

```
use db_clientes
create table tbl_proprietarios
(
ID_proprietario SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
name varchar(50) not null,
email varchar(50) not null,
ID_cond SMALLINT NOT NULL, --Faltou criar o atributo nessa tabela
constraint ID_cond foreign key (ID_cond) 
references tbl_cond(ID_cond)
)
```

Recomendaria o seguinte também:

- Verificar os nomes das colunas no comando (case sensitive);
- Não colocar o nome da `constraint` com o mesmo nome das colunas;
- Verificar se os atributos contém o mesmo tipo.